# Find a length of a sub list of a list Python

Tags: python, list

Im currently writing a program that needs to figure out the lengths of words in a sublist of a list and then add them together. Currently the code i have can either break out the list that is a sentence into individual words and now i need to find the lengths of the individual words in the sublist. Whenever i use counter_split_list, it counts the words in the sentence.

here is my code:

```
def split_by_whitespace (['It', 'is', 'a', 'truth', 'universally', 'acknowledged'], ['that', 'a', 'single', 'man', 'in', 'possession', 'of', 'a', 'good', 'fortune', 'must', 'be', 'in', 'want', 'of', 'a', 'wife']):
    l = my_string
    split_list =[i.split() for i in l]
    #counter_split_list=[len(i) for i in split_list]
    return(split_list)
```

[Words in Sublists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stuI0.png)

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Give an example of `my_string`, the result you're seeing, and the result you desire.

Comment: Try `[len(word) for lst in split_list for word in lst]`. But I don't suggest a one liner.

Comment: My input is a long list of strings i.e. ['It', 'is', 'a', 'truth', 'universally', 'acknowledged', 'that', 'a', 'single', 'man', 'in', 'possession', 'of', 'a', 'good', 'fortune', 'must', 'be', 'in', 'want', 'of', 'a', 'wife'], which is what i get from the function above. whenver I add back in counter_split_list i get: [23] which is the count of the words. Im expecting [2,2,1,5 etc.] basically looking for the amount of letters per word so i can add them together and average them to find amount of words per sentence and mean amount of words per sentence

Comment: I also need to keep the same grouping of words so like the first sentence would look like, [2,2,1,5,2,3],[2,3,1,4,2] if that makes sense

Comment: can you add your input string? Please add an as an example for my_string so we can test it.

Comment: Its been added to the code

Comment: I'm assuming that some of the strings may consist of multiple words, separated by spaces?  E.g. `["word1 word2", "word3"]`  In this case, what is the desired output?  Is it `[10, 5]`?  Or `[5, 5, 5]`?  Or something else?  Or will there be no spaces in any of the strings?

Comment: The reason I ask is because of the use of `split`, which only makes sense if you're expecting to see spaces.  And the posted code won't work, since you're providing actual arguments to a function definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, your input is not a string but a list of lists. These sub-lists contain words as shown in your input example. If that's the case, then the following function would return the length of each word for you as you wanted it.

```
# Modified version of your function

def split_by_whitespace (my_string):
  sentence_all_len = []
  for sentence in my_string:
    sentence_len = [len(word) for word in sentence]
    sentence_all_len.append(sentence_len)
  return sentence_all_len

# I assume your input looks like this as you provided in your question, though in a wrong way. 
list_of_strings = [['It', 'is', 'a', 'truth', 'universally', 'acknowledged'], ['that', 'a', 'single', 'man', 'in', 'possession', 'of', 'a', 'good', 'fortune', 'must', 'be', 'in', 'want', 'of', 'a', 'wife']]

# Output statement with a call to your function with the list of lists as an input
print(split_by_whitespace(list_of_strings)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 2, 1, 5, 11, 12], [4, 1, 6, 3, 2, 10, 2, 1, 4, 7, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 4]]
```